# Calculating the average of fluctuations of a given time series

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, integration, turbulence

I have a given data set, 4500 time data points approx, and the instantaneous velocity at each point. To calculate the time average of the velocity, I attempted to integrate the velocity function numerically wrt each time step using the trapezoid method and devided by the total time interval $T_{4500} - T_1$.
The time average was calculated as: $$\bar{U} = \frac{1}{T_{4500}-T_1}\sum_{i=1}^{4500} \frac{u(t_{i+1})+u(t_i)}{2}*(t_{i+1} - t_i)$$
I calculated the fluctuation at each time-step $i$:
$$u_i' = u_i - \bar{U}$$
I am a bit unsure on how to take the average of the fluctuation terms, if I take the sum and divide it by the total number of points (4500) I get 0.031 (a term close to zero); on the other hand, if I divide the sum by the the time interval $T_{4500}-T_{1}$ I get a value of 2. The second value confuses me as I expect the average of the fluctuations to be zero, should I only consider the point avg rather than the time average of the fluctuations?
Picture of the instantaneous speed data as a function of time:
[image]

Comment: What kind of motion are you looking at here? Random motion (like Brownian motion) or something on a well defined trajectory? If it's a trajectory, then one should first fit the data to an appropriate dynamical model and then remove the resulting fit from the data and check if the residuals have the expected statistical properties for a random process or a random measurement error.

Comment: It is not clear what is the relation between the formula containing $u$s and the first sum. What is the instantaneous fluctuation? $u_i$? In principle, the average of the fluctuations should be done in the same way as the average value.

Comment: @FlatterMann let me add a picture of the plotted data; showing the average value I calculated trying to do the numerical integration.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 thank you for pointing that out, I have fixed the naming of my variables.

Comment: I would guess that either $u'_i = U - u_i$, or $u'_i = u_i - U$.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 my sincere apologies mate, that was a mistake on my end, my excel sheet has the $u_i - \bar{U}$ formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time average of a continuous variable can be defined in a quite natural way as
$$
U = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t) dt.
$$
Every discretization of such integral can be thought of as a weighted average of $N$ sampled data, with a weight depending on the spacing between successive data. It is well-known that if the weights are equal (equally spaced points) the weighted average coincides with the arithmetic average.

Therefore, if you define the average valued of the 4500 data as
$$\bar{U} = \frac{1}{t_{4500}-t_1}\sum_{i=1}^{4499} \frac{u(t_{i+1})+u(t_i)}{2}*(t_{i+1} - t_i),$$ (notice the correction to the upper limit of the index, to avoid to introduce a $4501$-th point).
The same formula, with $u'_i$ in place of $u_i$, should be used. By construction, it should be exactly equal to zero.

Of course, the average fluctuation is not an interesting quantity. More interesting the mean squared fluctuation, i.e., the average of the squared fluctuations, against to be evaluated with the same formula, substituting $u^{'2}_i$ to $u_i$.